# Arch install hangs on Windows 11 Hyper-V VM

Tags: arch-linux, hyper-v

I'm trying to install Arch Linux in a Windows 11 Hyper-V VM. The ISO I use is archlinux-2022.06.01-x86_64.iso.

When starting the VM, it shows a menu where I can choose between

- Arch Linux install medium (x86_64, UEFI)
- Arch Linux install medium
  (x86_64, UEFI) with speech
- Arch Linux install medium (x86_64, UEFI,
  Copy to RAM)
- Arch Linux install medium (x86_64, UEFI, Copy to RAM)
  with speech
- EFI Shell
- Reboot Into Firmware Interface

I choose the first. Then the install hangs on a black screen. I do not get a command prompt. In the Hyper-V manager I can see that the VM is using some CPU (it says 8%). I let it run for 15 minutes, but nothing happens.

I've disabled secure boot on the VM as I can understand that you need to do that.

I have an Ubuntu VM that runs fine, fwiw.

Why does it hang?

Edit: These are the Hyper-V settings. It's a Generation 2 VM.

[image]

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I've added the full menu. I thought that maybe people that knew Arch were familiar with it so I wouldn't have to type it all.

Comment: I've just gone with the default VM configuration, except disabling secure boot and bumping memory up to 4GB from 2GB. I've added a screenshot of the VM settings. You can't see it there, but I've checked that it is a Gen 2 VM.

Comment: I've verified the ISO by checking the SHA256 checksum. It should be good. I've tried changing the VM settings to the ones you have, but it didn't help.

Comment: Bummer :( .. perhaps someone will come along that can help you and knows WHY it is doing what it is doing.

Comment: Try closing the VM Connection window (keeping the VM running), then reopening it. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Meet the same issue with archlinux-2023.03.01-x86_64.iso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the archlinux-2022.05.01-x86_64.iso image and that installs like it should. The June image must have an issue with Hyper-V or my machine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disabling indirect branch tracking, it's commited by intel in the newest kernel. And it's not compatible with hyper-v now.

Press `e` on the boot menu, add `ibt=off` to the linux parameter. Then press ctrl+x, it would boot fine then.

ref: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=281111

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue when running with image archlinux-2023.05.03-x86_64.iso. It's almost a year since this issue was first reported is there a plan to fix the image so manual editing is not required. I did not see anything about this in the docs:

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hyper-V

Adding ibt=off to the end of the Linux command line worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, works for me.

Except, in hyper-v, to edit the current line,

In the installation ISO boot;

- I needed to press the TAB key instead of the ’e’ key.

When actually booting the installed disk;

- I needed to press ’e’

To add "ibt=off" at the end of the linux boot CMD variable.

I am probably writing this only for my futur me, googling again for the same ibt=off stuff in hyper-v... -_-